# Changing sequence of BinaryReader after software release

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, binaryreader, binarywriter

I am using a Unity3D serialization tool that uses BinaryReader and Writer.
Saving players game state with this tool. The disadvantage of sequential reading and writing is you must read that file in same order evertime.

When i want to add new variable to a class, it is breaking the read order

```
public override void Write(object obj, ES2Writer writer)
{
    SettingsBrigde data = (SettingsBrigde)obj;
    writer.Write(data.FxVolume);
    writer.Write(data.MusicVolume);
    writer.Write(data.shadow);
    writer.Write(data.isBaterySave);
    writer.Write(data.controllerType);
    writer.Write(data.qualityPreset);
    //New variables after game release
    writer.Write(data.mynewvariable);
}

public override void Read(ES2Reader reader, object c)
{
    SettingsBrigde data = (SettingsBrigde)c;
    data.FxVolume = reader.Read<System.Single>();
    data.MusicVolume = reader.Read<System.Single>();
    data.shadow = reader.Read<System.Boolean>();
    data.isBaterySave = reader.Read<System.Boolean>();
    data.controllerType = reader.Read<TouchInputLayout>();
    data.qualityPreset = reader.Read<QualitySetttingsOptions>();
    //New variables after game release
    data.mynewvariable = reader.Read<System.Single>();
}
```

As you can see if i read that file after new update it will read wrong data or throw exception acording to stream's next state.

There is a temporary solution, i am writing file version first. And reading that version to determine what will i read in the next step

```
public override void Write(object obj, ES2Writer writer)
{
    fileVersion = 2;
    SettingsBrigde data = (SettingsBrigde)obj;
    writer.Write(fileVersion);
    writer.Write(data.FxVolume);
    writer.Write(data.MusicVolume);
    writer.Write(data.shadow);
    writer.Write(data.isBaterySave);
    writer.Write(data.controllerType);
    writer.Write(data.qualityPreset);
    //New variables after game release
    writer.Write(data.mynewvariable);
}

public override void Read(ES2Reader reader, object c)
{
    SettingsBrigde data = (SettingsBrigde)c;
    int currentVersion = reader.Read<System.Int32>();
    data.FxVolume = reader.Read<System.Single>();
    data.MusicVolume = reader.Read<System.Single>();
    data.shadow = reader.Read<System.Boolean>();
    data.isBaterySave = reader.Read<System.Boolean>();
    data.controllerType = reader.Read<TouchInputLayout>();
    data.qualityPreset = reader.Read<QualitySetttingsOptions>();
    //New variables after game release
    if (currentVersion == 2)
    {
        data.mynewvariable = reader.Read<System.Single>();
    }
}
```

I am looking for more decent solution if you have.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We're using versioning ourselves for each message we get. Our server side is never sure if a client is updated so we can always get old versions from a client which we still have to support as long as not all clients are updated.

In your case, you seem to be sure that you only have to support one version. Therefore you can update all player settings when you update the game. Read the settings in, add an extra default value and save them again. This way you only have to support one version.

Comment: When game being initialized. Looking for a save file if exist. After succeeding it is loading . In my case, if player doesn't trigger Write method it is going to read in last version order that user have. So even after 5 revisions when user come back it is reading properly